# Convert large decimal numbers to hexadecimal

Tags: php, precision, largenumber

I  had to convert a large decimal number to hexadecimal so i use the function `dechex`.

So my code go like these :

```
$large_number = '637188198442990866068821375'
$large_hex = dechex($large_number)
```

but when i print the variable `$large`

```
echo $large
```

i got these value `7fffffffffffffff` and i am very sure that i lose some precision.

What can i do to get the full precision in these operation ?

Answer (score 0):

The largest `integer` that Javascript can handle is `2^52`. +/- `9007199254740992`

[What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t)

You'll either need to slice up your integer before it hits Javascript or look at one of the Big Integer libraries.